# Windows 7 takes three minutes to shutdown, yet event log is empty

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

My Windows 7's shutdown process is taking too long, so I created a custom Event Viewer view to review all events from all logs during the delay. The trouble is, the event log has nothing recorded.  For example, I initiated a system restart (Start > Restart) at 12:51:09pm today.

[image]

Do you know where I can trace or what I can chase to see what happens after Event ID 13?  Or find what causes the delay?  I can swear that Windows is still running a shutdown/hourglass screen after 12:51pm.

Comment: does shutdown -f take the same time?

Comment: Do you have anything like OffLine files?

Comment: soandos, yes. so does shutdown -f -r. sgmoore, no.

Comment: Try doing it as another user. It may be a bad profile. Also, if you want to so that command, do shutdown -s -f -t 00 (s=shutdown, f=force so you don't have to end task on anything, t 00=do it immediately.

Comment: please, download and run "process explorer" (www.sysinternals.com) and see all processes running on your computer. right click on column header and check "command line" to see from where the processes are started. then use "save as" to save a txt file with all informations showed, open it, copy and paste that here and so we can see if the problem is a running process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the first thing to do is to try a shutdown in safe mode and if that works, use MSConfig to disable all non essential services and startup processes and test again. If that works, you start enabling them until you get it to go wrong.

One very simple method, which sometimes helps, is to open task manager and switch to processes and leave this open while you try to shutdown. Quite often task manager will remain open long enough for you to see what processes are taking a long time to shutdown and may identity the fault. (In some case, task manager will shutdown early, but you can restart it again)

Another alternative is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals/Microsoft which may show you what is happening (eg file/network activity) when you shutdown.

At the advanced level Microsoft have some performance tools which are designed to help OEM's trace and diagnose startup and shutdown problems. I have never used them and given their target market, they may be complicated to use, but if you are interested search for Xbootmgr.exe

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Performance Information and Tools > Advanced Tools

Are there any performance issues reported there?

.

You can also do a clean boot, then re-enable Non Microsoft programs and services one at a time to possibly find the offending one that slows shutdown.

[See this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-is-very-slow-to-shutdown/fb35a679-c9b8-4a97-95c4-39c60e218130)